# Angular Service Worker, caching api calls for offline app

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, angular5, angular-service-worker

I'm trying to make the service worker in angular work with API requests.
I'd like the app to work offline and I've the below config:

```
    {
        "name": "api",
        "urls": ["https://x.com/**"],
        "cacheConfig": {
            "strategy": "performance",
            "maxSize": 20,
            "maxAge": "365d",
            "timeout": "5s"
        }
    }
```

Here is what the xhr tab looks like when I'm offline:

[image]

and this is the content of the user request:

[image]

As you can see the API calls for user don't resolve.

This is what the response of `user` looks like when  online:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

- Go to your application tab -> Clear Storage -> Clear Site Data.
- Change your DataGroups array from this:

  ```
  {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": ["https://x.com/**"],
      "cacheConfig": {
          "strategy": "performance",
          "maxSize": 20,
          "maxAge": "365d",
          "timeout": "5s"
      }
  }
  ```

To this:

```
"dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/user" //<=========== I know you want all API calls to be cached, but try this first and see
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d"
      }
    }
  ]
```

- save and build your app in `PROD`,
- visit the page the first time.
- disable network
- refresh your page

Comment: hi, I have a query on this. if am caching my API call and any data change happened in my database how I will get the updated data. is there anyway. this might be a dumb question since am new to service worker concept pardon me

Comment: Thanks Nadhir - just one thing i want to add. when i added your text above as-is, the PWA worked on localhost, but didnt on PROD. so next time, before the build, i added your text to the ngsw.json file and the build made your text into... "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "patterns": [
        "\\/user"
      ],
      "strategy": "performance",
      "maxSize": 100,
      "maxAge": 518400000,
      "version": 1
    }] ... which worked perfectly :)

Comment: It worked for me as well. Nadhir, would you please explain? What if his app would collect data from more than one source, and the second url also ends with /user, but what if he doesn't want to cache that second source/url? Why do full urls (https://x.com/user) not work?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "strategy": "performance" remove timeout property

Answer (score -2):

To handle API data offline you have to use Offline Storage (that is store data in web browser after initial API call), recently I have used Local Forage in my application. Find the linkS below:

https://github.com/Alorel/ngforage#types-and-polyfills

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I believe service workers are able to cache API calls on their own without requiring any storage. So this question is aimed at service workers

Comment: i don't think it will work with one config file, if so please post the worked solution. i strongly believe we have to use offline storage.

Comment: Now that I think of it, even if it worked, if I requested products, then made changes on those, then when starting the app offline I wouldn't have the changes. So you might be right

Comment: Normally, I would only cache the urls that request data. Thus, saving would not work (you'd get an error right away, because you're not online). Sure, if you'd want to cache `/videos**` and not exclude `/videos/**/update`, and the save would be done on `/videos/id/update` then that might be an issue I guess.
Also, I wouldn't cache POST requests. Those are usually updating data or having to do with authorization/login submit etc.

Comment: nice to hear  Ced, if come up with any good solution please share.

Answer (score -3):

```
"dataGroups": [
    {

        "name": "TestApi",
        "urls": [
            "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
            "https://localhost:4377/api/home/getNames/"
        ],
        "cacheConfig": {
            "strategy": "freshness",
            "maxSize": 20,
            "maxAge": "1h",
            "timeout": "5s"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "TestAPI",
        "urls": [
            "https://localhost:4377/api/test/getList",
            "https://localhost:4377/api/template/start/"
        ],
        "cacheConfig": {
            "strategy": "performance",
            "maxSize": 20,
            "maxAge": "2h",
            "timeout": "5s"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: if you want to cache api calls using pwa, you can define datagroups in ngsw-config.json file.