# Chrome is getting slow after days of using Angular App

Tags: angular, google-chrome, browser-cache, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Our customer is using our angular5 app in google chrome (PWA) on android devise. 
He using the app 16hours a day non stop (its about ordering food/drinks in a restaurant).
After a few days, the app is getting slower and slower. After clearing browser cache, the app is fast again.

Any suggestion? Or maybe is this a normal behavior?

Comment: Be carefully if in your PWA you're also caching the API

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi can you explain this more detailed pls?

Comment: usually pwa also cache API GEt response .. so maybe this is why it's getting heavy and heavy after h of use... you can set it to DON'T cache them and always use network.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419769/angular-service-worker-caching-api-calls-for-offline-app

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi if the pwa would cache the api response, i would see it in the Application/Cache/Cache Storage? Because there i only see the assets things

Answer (score 3):

This is not standard behavior for SPA. For some reason your application is growing up in the memory. Most probably reasons:

- **memory leak** (like unclosed subscriptions)
- **caching too much data** (aka in-memory cache)

Use Google Chrome Developer Tools to find and prevent memory leaks (tab Performance).